# В PHP не работают встроенные константы _FILE_ и _LINE_

Tags: php, denwer

Помогите!

Я недавно купил книгу по PHP - там написано: "Существует несколько предопределённых констант `_FILE_`, `_LINE_`, `PHP_VERSION` ..." и так далее, но у меня работают все кроме `_FILE_` и `_LINE_` (у меня на компе `Denwer3_Base_2010-11-07_a2.2.4_p5.3.1_m5.1.40_pma3.2.3.exe`). Может, в моем PHP не хватает каких-тo библиотек? Или эти константы под WINDOWS не работают? Помогите. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Читать тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.predefined.php)

Подскажу - 2 подчеркивания с обоих сторон =)

Comment: А почему в книге Дмитрия Котерова и Алексея Костарёва написано одно подчёркивание?

Comment: А если честно, не в курсе. Мобыть ошибочка вышла, ну и вообще я не помню, чтоб они с одной писались.

Comment: > А почему в книге Дмитрия Котерова и Алексея Костарёва написано одно подчёркивание?

На заборе тоже много чего написано. Первоисточником информации и настольной книгой любого PHP программиста должен быть [php.net][1]


  [1]: http://php.net/constants.predefined

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент актуальная версия - PHP5, и [ссылка](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/) на библиотеку от самих разработчиков сразу на русскую базу. А лучше всего ставьте xampp (в связке apache2 + mysql + php + ещё что-то) и не парьтесь.